# Are Yusuke and Jin half brothers?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

I recently finished watching Yu Yu Hakusho and in that there was a fight between Jin and one of Yusuke's fathers friends, where the opponent said that "I had a chance to fight with your father the thunder god!" and then goes to a flashback where they show him fighting with a guy looking just like his father

I then did some searching around in the internet and when I search for "Thunder god Yu Yu Hakusho" I still get Yusuke's dad, so is Raizen the thunder god? then does that mean Yusuke and Jin are half brothers??? can anyone help me get clarity on this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Raizen is actually Yusuke's distant ancestor. They just call him his father for convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the episode you were talking about: *Episode 107: The Demon World Tournament Begins*. The episode includes the battle between Jin and Soketsu, one of Raizen's old friends. According to the subtitles on Funimation's site, Soketsu never mentions Jin's father. There is a flashback to a fight between Raizen and Soketsu, however. Soketsu mentions that Jin is tenacious just like he was when he fought Raizen. Jin and Soketsu go on to say they both want to fight the son of Raizen (Yusuke).  This wiki page mentions that Soketsu erroneously calls Jin the son of Raizen in a variant of the English dub: http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/Souketsu.

So, Jin is not really the son of Raizen. This is just an error in translation. Even if he was, he wouldn't be Yusuke's brother (or half-brother). Yusuke and other characters call Raizen Yusuke's father, but he actually isn't. Raizen is Yusuke's ancestor, not his father.

**Conclusion: Jin and Yusuke are not brothers**

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, can finally get this thought out of mind. Would have been interesting if it were true though :D, thanks again